# Problem in running Tensorflow-GPU on offline environment under window-7 x64

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I'm trying to use tensorflow-gpu library in offline environment (windows 64).
My python version is 3.6 for 64 bit and I'm using Anaconda3 interpreter (5.2.0 version).
Cuda 9.2 and cuddn 7.1.4 (download from https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)

I downloaded tensorflow-1.2.1-py36_0.tar.bz2 and tensorflow-gpu-1.1.0-np112py36_0.tar.bz2 and installed the files using Conda install.
I see that the libraries appeared under "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages", but although tensorflow (under cpu) is running well, when trying to run tensorflow-gpu I get the error **"_pywrap_tensorflow_internal"**.

Environment variables:

```
CUDA_HOME: c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2

CUDA_PATH: c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2

CUDA_PATH_V9_2: c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2
```

Path:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\extras\CUPTI\libx64;c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\lib\x64;c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin;c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\libnvvp;
```

I am also try to install  tensorflow-gpu-1.10 with CUDA 9.2 and CuDNN 7.1.4 and I received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CUDA version 9.0 instead, It is explicitly stated in the [Tensorflow installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) that 9.0 is required. Downgrading to an earlier version solved the issue for me.

Comment: I already try to downgrading to 9.0 and unfortunately that not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You installed tensorflow 1.1, which requires CUDA 8.0 and CuDNN 5.1 to run on the GPU.

Comment: Hi, I install CUDA 8.0 and CuDNN 5.1 ,unfortunately I received the same error message